# IPython automatically turning on matplotlib interactive mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, conda, miniconda

I'm experiencing some newly odd behavior from IPython. I just had to do a clean reinstall of my miniconda, so I now have fresh IPython and Matplotlib versions. It turns out that IPython is automatically switching matplotlib to interactive mode (which has the annoying side effect of making my saved figures blank in my scripts, because they save after I close the window).

Here's an example:

```
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 21:52:21) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.6.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import matplotlib as mpl                                                                                                                              

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                       

In [3]: mpl.is_interactive()                                                                                                                                  
Out[3]: False

In [4]: plt.plot([1,2])                                                                                                                                       
Out[4]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f0b0b048940>]

In [5]: mpl.is_interactive()                                                                                                                                  
Out[5]: True
```

Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Note, I've tested the same code in regular python and interactive mode stays off.

Comment: It's a long shot, but check your IPython `.*rc` files? They likely weren't overwritten since (if I remember right) they live somewhere in your home folder.

Comment: Interactive mode is needed for the figure to be responsive while at the same time being able to continue using the IPython console and updating the plot. So maybe you want to go into detail about the problem you have with the interactive mode being on?!

Comment: i experience the same issue. Interestingly if i call plt.ioff() after your last line and then call plt.figure() again, then the interactive is NOT turned on anymore. Seems like it is an issue with the first call of figure() that switches interactive mode on.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest when interactive mode is on, then figures pop up, which takes time to draw and it is very annoying when one doesn't want to see them, but just save them instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the interplay between matplotlib and IPython, which got introduced in matplotlib version 3.1.0 (via [#12637](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12637)). It will be fixed in matplotlib 3.2 (via [#14979](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14979)).

Options you have:

- revert to matplotlib 3.0.3
- Use the [current matplotlib development version](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib)
- Wait for matplotlib 3.2 to be released (scheduled for September 2019)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this version of ipython/matplotlib would be to define a custom ioff():

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

def my_ioff():
  f = plt.figure()
  plt.close(f)
  plt.ioff()

my_ioff()
print(mpl.is_interactive())
f = plt.figure()
print(mpl.is_interactive())
-----------
-> False
-> False
```

Whereas before we had:

```
plt.ioff()
print(mpl.is_interactive())
f = plt.figure()
print(mpl.is_interactive())
-----------
-> False
-> True
```