# Suppress plot window when creating figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

For years I have created figures using some rendition of the following code:

```
import pylab as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(3.5, 2.5))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Earlier this week I had to reinstall Python using the most-recent Anaconda Python 3.7 release (previous version was also 3.7).  The problem is when I create my figure the figure window appears immediately (normally the figure window would never appear until I called fig.show()).  I checked the matplotlib backend to see if it was different, but it is set to qt5agg.  I don't think the backend is the problem.  Does anyone know of a recent change in matplotlib that would cause the figures to pop up...anyone know how to prevent them from popping up without setting the backent to agg?

Current matplotlib version: 3.1.1

Comment: This should still be the case. Did you change the way you run python? Where do you type in your code?

Comment: No, everything else is the same.  I do editing and testing in IPython in emacs.  I just did a test: when running IPython in the terminal the figure window still pops up, when running python in the terminal the figure window does NOT pop up.  Can IPython be configured to cause this?

Comment: Yes, IPython does this by default. There is also [some bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14979) in the matplotlib/IPython interaction, which might be solved in the upcoming matplotlib 3.2.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Weird, I've used IPython for years and never had this problem (maybe something was broken before and it is now working correctly?).  Do you know of a way to switch off this behavior in IPython?

Comment: Well, usually calling `plt.ioff()` should do it, but due to that bug, it may not have any effect in matplotlib 3.1.

Comment: Actually, you can try using 3.1.2, which would include this fix.

Comment: Calling pl.ioff() does the trick, but I'd hate to call this in every script.  Weird thig is, I have an even older installation of python (3.6) that does not do this.

Comment: There is actually already a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153840/ipython-automatically-turning-on-matplotlib-interactive-mode

Comment: I didn't realize this was part of the bug.  I remove anaconda and installed the previous 3.7 release (2019.03 build) that uses matplotlib 3.0.3 and that fixed the problem.  Thanks for the help.